# How do I share .net 4 assembly between Mvc app and winforms app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, .net-4.0

The problem arises because the WinForms application is a .NET4 client profile whereas the service assembly I'm using within the ASP.NET Mvc App is full .NET4 profile.  How can I share the assembly between both projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a client profile targeted assembly with the full profile but not the contrary. So you could build an assembly targeting the client profile and use it within your ASP.NET MVC application which is targeting the full profile. But you cannot build an assembly targeting the full profile and use it in a WinForms application that is targeting the client profile unless you switch the targeting profile of this WinForms application to the full profile.

So I guess you will have to target the client profile for the assembly in question if you want to reuse it in both projects.